# Error trying to Insert into Mysql database ex.tostring because of vbcrlf

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I've wrote this code:

```
Try
    Uff_IdW = Me.DataGridView1.Item(DgvCol, IdWInsDB).Value.ToString.Trim().Split("_")
    If Uff_IdW.Length = 2 Then SplitOk = True Else SplitOk = False
Catch ex As Exception
    mErr = "split error: " & ex.ToString
    SQLStr = "INSERT INTO errlog (Sect, ErrDescr) VALUES ('GP', '" & Errore & "')"
    InsertDBase(cnString, SQLStr)
    SplitOk = False
End Try
```

but the insert query doesn't work because of a "vbcrlf" into the ex.tostring.

The query string resulted from code appears like this:

```
"INSERT INTO errlog (Sect, ErrDescr) VALUES ('GP', 'split error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." & vbCrLf & "   in Test_GP.Form1.FirstOption_DGV_Click(Int32 DgvRow, Int32 DgvCol)')"
```

How can I fix this and insert into my Database the ex.tostring without errors?

Comment: learn how to write queries that aren't vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: @MarcB I'm not afraid of sql injection because I'm working on a local and not shared database but I'll read the link you posted. Do you think that using something for preventing sql injection can also avoid the error I've got?

Comment: just because you're working locally doesn't make you immune to injection. your very own query above proves that you ARE vulnerable. go read the site, it has links on various languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Replace` function on the string to strip out the carriage return:

```
SQLStr = "INSERT INTO errlog (Sect, ErrDescr) VALUES ('GP', '" & Errore & "')"
SQLStr = SQLStr.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ")
InsertDBase(cnString, SQLStr)
```